# Find all $(x,y)$ such that $\sin x+\sin y=\sin(x+y)$ and $|x|+|y|=1$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all $(x,y)$ such that $$\sin x+\sin y=\sin(x+y)$$ and $|x|+|y|=1$

My work:
We have, $\sin x+\sin y=\sin x\cos y+\cos x \sin y$
By comparing both sides, we have,$\cos y=1,\cos x=1$, but certainly that is not true, as $|x|+|y|=1$.
So,$\sin x(1-\cos y)=\sin y(\cos x-1)$
Now, I am stuck. I cannot break this loop to proceed further. Please help!

Comment: I don't see how you can reach the conclusion $\cos y=1$ and $\sin y =1$. you cannot 'equate coefficients' because it is not an identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas,

$$\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\frac{x+y}2\cos\frac{x-y}2$$

$$\sin(x+y)=2\sin\frac{x+y}2\cos\frac{x+y}2$$

So, $$\sin x+\sin y-\sin(x+y)=2\sin\frac{x+y}2\left(\cos\frac{x-y}2-\cos\frac{x+y}2\right)$$
$$=2\sin\frac{x+y}2\cdot2\sin\frac x2\sin\frac y2 (\text{ again Prosthaphaeresis })$$

Now we know $\displaystyle \sin A=0\implies A=n\pi$ where $n$ is an integer

As $|x|+|y|=1, |x|=1-|y|\le 1$

**Case** $1a)$  If $\displaystyle \sin\frac x2=0\iff x=2n\pi\implies|2n\pi|\le1\implies|n|<1\implies n=0\implies x=0$

$\displaystyle|y|=1\iff y=\pm1$

**Case** $1b)$ Similarly,  if $\displaystyle \sin\frac y2=0$

**Case** $2)$ If  $\displaystyle \sin\frac{x+y}2=0, x+y=2n\pi$

Using [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/ComplexNumberInequalities.shtml), $\displaystyle |x+y|\le |x|+|y|=1\implies |2n\pi|\le1\implies |n|<1\implies n=0$

$\displaystyle\implies x+y=0$ and we have $\displaystyle|x|+|y|=1$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: and also you can get $x = -0.5$ and $y=0.5$ or vice versa for $x+y/2 = n\pi$

Comment: How to prove, this is the only possible solution and no more solution exists?

Comment: @Hawk. I think that what lab answered is the best proof, moreover based on the simplest manner using basic identities.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes sir, I understand that. But, I was wondering how can I prove that these are the only solutions that can exist and no other solution exists any further.

Comment: Yes, I think I can do it. I will check it.

Comment: How will you justify the solutions $(1/2,-1/2),(-1/2,1/2)$

Comment: @Hawk, we have $y=-x$ and $|x|+|y|=1\implies |x|+|-x|=1\iff 2|x|=1\iff |x|=\frac12\implies x=\pm \frac12=-y$

Answer (score 1):

Considering $\sin(x)+\sin(y)=\sin(x+y)$, there will be solutions when $x=0$ or $y=0$ since $\sin(0)=0$.

From $|x|+|y|=1$ there are obvious solutions at $(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)$.

You should also consider four further possibilities:

- $x \in (0,1), y=1-x \gt 0$
- $x \in (0,1), y=x-1 \lt 0$
- $x \in (-1,0), y=1+x \ge 0$
- $x \in (-1,0), y=-x-1 \le 0$

You can show that the first and fourth give no solutions. The second and third give the additional solutions $\left(\frac12,-\frac12\right)$ and $\left(-\frac12,\frac12\right)$, which are also intuitively obvious since $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

from your identity $\sin x(1-\cos y)=\sin y(\cos x-1)$ we have 
$$ 2\sin\frac{x}2\cos\frac{x}2 2\sin^2\frac{y}2=-2\sin\frac{y}2\cos\frac{y}2 2\sin^2\frac{x}2
$$
so as long as $\sin\frac{x}2 \ne 0, \sin\frac{y}2 \ne 0$ this gives
$$ \cot \frac{x}2 = - \cot \frac{y}2 
$$ so $$\frac{x}2 = - \frac{y}2 + n\pi$$
clearly $n=0$ if $|x|+|y|=1$ hence $x= -y= \pm \frac12$

Comment: what happens when $\sin \frac{x}{2}=0$ and $\sin \frac{y}{2}=0$?

Comment: these values are ruled out by the condition $|x|+|y|=1$

Comment: But one of them can be zero?

Comment: Indeed, $x=0$, $y=\pm1$ are solutions; so are $x=\pm1$, $y=0$.